# New dataframe from conditions of multiple columns and dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following table:

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | True | True | True |
| 2 | False | False | True | False | False |

and I have the following dictionary:
`conditions = {'conditionA': ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], 'conditionB': ['col4', col5']`

How would I create a new pandas dataframe so that if any of columns are `True` in a key-value pair, the condition is True?

| index | ConditionA | ConditionB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | True |
| 2 | True | False |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({cond: df[cols].any(axis=1).tolist()
                      for cond, cols in conditions.items()},
                 index=df['index']).reset_index()

   index  conditionA  conditionB
0      1        True        True
1      2        True       False
```